# Python Pandas drop columns based on max value of column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Im just getting going with Pandas as a tool for munging two dimensional arrays of data. It's super overwhelming, even after reading the docs. You can do so much that I can't figure out how to do anything, if that makes any sense.

My dataframe (simplified):

```
Date       Stock1  Stock2   Stock3
2014.10.10  74.75  NaN     NaN
2014.9.9    NaN    100.95  NaN 
2010.8.8    NaN    NaN     120.45
```

So each column only has one value.

I want to remove all columns that have a max value less than x. So say here as an example, if x = 80, then I want a new DataFrame:

```
Date        Stock2   Stock3
2014.10.10   NaN     NaN
2014.9.9     100.95  NaN 
2010.8.8     NaN     120.45
```

How can this be acheived? I've looked at dataframe.max() which gives me a series. Can I use that, or have a lambda function somehow in select()?

Comment: I've looked at df.max() to get the max values of the column. Not sure what I can do with that object yet. I'm a total noob with Panda at the moment...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `df.max()` to index with.

```
In [19]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [23]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3), columns=['a','b','c'])

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
          a         b         c
0 -0.928912  0.220573  1.948065
1 -0.310504  0.847638 -0.541496
2 -0.743000 -1.099226 -1.183567


In [24]: df.max()
Out[24]: 
a   -0.310504
b    0.847638
c    1.948065
dtype: float64
```

Next, we make a boolean expression out of this:

```
In [31]: df.max() > 0
Out[31]: 
a    False
b     True
c     True
dtype: bool
```

Next, you can index df.columns by this (this is called boolean indexing):

```
In [34]: df.columns[df.max() > 0]
Out[34]: Index([u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')
```

Which you can finally pass to DF:

```
In [35]: df[df.columns[df.max() > 0]]
Out[35]: 
          b         c
0  0.220573  1.948065
1  0.847638 -0.541496
2 -1.099226 -1.183567
```

Of course, instead of 0, you use any value that you want as the cutoff for dropping.

Comment: `df.loc[:,df.max() > 0]` can be a better approach to select in general, because that gives you a handle you can use to modify the original frame.

Comment: Ya, that is a smart solution.  You should post it as a separate answer.